# Website menu with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I wrote some code in Flask for site menu:

```
def menu(parent_id=0, menutree=None):
    menutree = menutree or []
    cur = g.db.execute('select id, parent, alias, title, ord from static where parent="'+ str(parent_id) +'" and ord>0 order by ord')
    fetch = cur.fetchall()

    if not fetch:
        return None

    return [{'id':raw[0], 'parent':raw[1], 'alias':raw[2], 'title':raw[3], 'sub':menu(raw[0])} for raw in fetch]
```

The data is taken from the sqlite3 table:

```
create table static (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  parent integer,
  alias string not null,
  title string not null,
  text string not null,
  ord integer
);
```

Variable (menu_list) is transmitted to template in each route:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    menu_list = menu()
    [...]
    return render_template('index.tpl', **locals())
```

Despite the fact that the code is more or less normal (except for prepared statements in a query to the database), the template is not very good:

```
<nav role="navigation">
  {% for menu in menu_list %}
  <li>
    <a{% if page_id == menu.id %} class="active"{% endif %} href="/{{ menu.alias }}">{{ menu.title }}</a>
    {% if menu.sub %}
    <ul>
      {% for sub in menu.sub %}
      <li><a href="/{{ menu.alias }}/{{ sub.alias }}">{{ sub.title }}</a>
        {% if sub.sub %}
        <ul>
          {% for subsub in sub.sub %}
          <li><a href="/{{ menu.alias }}/{{ sub.alias }}/{{ subsub.alias }}">{{ subsub.title }}</a>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

Is it possible to improve the existing code / output / logic?

Answer (score 3):

In this code, at first I didn't see the "danger" until I scrolled to the right by accident:

> ```
> def menu(parent_id=0, menutree=None):
>     menutree = menutree or []
>     cur = g.db.execute('select id, parent, alias, title, ord from static where parent="'+ str(parent_id) +'" and ord>0 order by ord')
>     fetch = cur.fetchall()
>
>     if not fetch:
>         return None
>
>     return [{'id':raw[0], 'parent':raw[1], 'alias':raw[2], 'title':raw[3], 'sub':menu(raw[0])} for raw in fetch]
> ```

In the `g.db.execute` statement you're embedding a parameter and we cannot know where the parameter comes from and if it was properly validated to prevent SQL injection. Two things to do here:

1. Make the line shorter, especially when it contains potentially dangerous stuff in the far right
2. Use prepared statements with `?` placeholder

It's not clear what kind of database you're using, so you might need to edit, but it should be something like this, shorter and without embedded parameters:

```
cur = g.db.execute('select id, parent, alias, title, ord '
                   'from static where parent = ? and ord > 0 '
                   'order by ord', parent_id)
```

Another small tip here, if you reverse the checking logic of `if not fetch` to `if fetch` at the end, you don't need to `return None`, as that's the default anyway, and the method will be a bit shorter:

```
def menu(parent_id=0, menutree=None):
    menutree = menutree or []
    cur = g.db.execute('select id, parent, alias, title, ord '
                       'from static where parent = ? and ord > 0 '
                       'order by ord', parent_id)
    fetch = cur.fetchall()

    if fetch:
        return [{'id': raw[0], 'parent': raw[1], 'alias': raw[2],
                 'title': raw[3], 'sub': menu(raw[0])} for raw in fetch]
```

And a tiny thing, [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) dictates to put a space after the `:` in a `key:value` pair, like so: `key: value`.

---

In this code:

> ```
> @app.route('/')
> def index():
>     menu_list = menu()
>     [...]
>     return render_template('index.tpl', **locals())
> ```

I recommend to NOT include all `**locals()`, but use the list of variables you want to pass explicitly. We're all humans, one day you might accidentally expose something.